Access change dates on other date fields based on date in first date field
I am relatively new at Access and need to find a way that when one date is selected, the other 3 date fields are updated.  I am guessing a query would be best.  My fields are:
Week Start Date  This date will be selected from a combo box so that a wrong date is not entered.
Week Finish Date (6 days after the start date)
Invoice Date (9 days after the start date)
Check Date (13 days after the start date)
Your assistance is appreciated.
I tried doing a query, however, the syntax I used is apparently incorrect:
SELECT DateAdd("d",6,[WeekStartDate]) AS NewDate FROM [tblStartDates]

You do not need a query. Just use the VBA DateAdd function in the AfterUpdate event of your StartDate ComboBox. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function

Name your controls:
cboStartDate
txtWeekFinishDate
txtcboInvoiceDate
txtcboCheckDate
Private Sub cboStartDate_AfterUpdate()
    'BM 2024-JUN-14 post 78624239 Update the other date controls after cboStartDate is updated using DateAdd "d" (days) 
   If IsDate(cboStartDate.Value) Then          
      txtWeekFinishDate.Value = DateAdd("d",6,cboStartDate.Value) 
      txtInvoiceDate.Value = DateAdd("d",9,cboStartDate.Value) 
      txtCheckDate.Value = DateAdd("d",13,cboStartDate.Value) 
   Else
      'handle bad start dates. options include:
       'msgbox cboStartDate.Value + " is an invalid date"

       'txtWeekFinishDate.Value = ""
       'txtInvoiceDate.Value = ""
       'txtCheckDate.Value = ""

       'txtWeekFinishDate.Value = "Unable to calculate. Invalid start date."
       'txtInvoiceDate.Value = "Unable to calculate. Invalid start date."
       'txtCheckDate.Value = "Unable to calculate. Invalid start date."

   End If
End Sub


The calculated date controls are most likely textboxes, not comboboxes.

@Gustav good call. Answer updated.

You might also consider using datepicker controls. On the list of controls select the horizontal line above a down arrow with the tooltip "More". From the list of 3 options select active X. Then from the big list select "Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0 (SP4)"

Sometimes the value you choose for StartDate is decided based on the values calculated for the other dates. To see more immediate calculations you can use the OnChange event instead of AfterUpdate.  This will do the calculations while you are editing the text within StartDate. You must use theStartDate.Text property in the calculation instead of StartDate.Value because StartDate.Value only changes after the focus leaves the control. With this strategy it is best to adjust the error handling to be less intrusive (no msgbox calls).

Thanks very much.  That is what I needed.  I have a separate issue that I will be posting soon which seems like I will need to use AfterUpdate again. I will post it shortly.

Then please mark as answered.
